# JavaScript. Filtering an array with the Splice() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-splice

I need to write a function

> filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b)

that takes an array and two numbers and deletes all elements from the array that are not within the range **a** to **b**. So the check looks like

> a ≤ arr[i] ≤ b

I want to do it with the for loop and splice method. But can't figure out why the function keeps some elements outside of the range, in my case below it's **number 3**. This is not a home task or whatever, I'm just practicing array methods. Here's my code:

```
let myArr = [1, 3,  8, 3, 9, 5, 3, 4, 10, 7, 6, 1]

function filterRangeInPlace( arr, a, b ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] < a || arr[i] > b ) {
            arr.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
}

filterRangeInPlace(myArr, 4, 9)

console.log(myArr) // [3, 8, 9, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

I understand I messed with the index somewhere, but can't figure out where and how, as the rest works fine. Thanks!

Comment: You must not increment the index if you remove an element, because this way you are skipping elements. Yet better is traversing the array from the end towards the beginning. This way you don't need to care about the indexes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start iterating from the end of the array if you are using splice here and go upto the first element as:

```
for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Let say, you are removing the first element i.e. `1` at position `0` then after removing the array will be

```
[3, 8, 3, 9, 5, 3, 4, 10, 7, 6, 1]
```

and at that time the `i` increments and becomes `1`, so now it will point to `8` as `1` index.

So using `splice` will skip some of the steps

```js
let myArr = [1, 3, 8, 3, 9, 5, 3, 4, 10, 7, 6, 1];

function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b) {
  for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] < a || arr[i] > b) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

filterRangeInPlace(myArr, 4, 9);
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: please dont post answers on obvious duplicates

Answer (score 1):

When you use `splice`, and you're still in the same loop, you skip some indexes (because splice deletes number of items, so the indexes are changed).

In your example, the `1`, which is first, is deleted, so `3` becomes the first one, but then you skip to the second (`i++` in the loop).  You don't double check the same index.

I'd recommend using `filter` method to do that, or just putting `i--` on the line after `splice`.

Comment: The requirment is to filter *in place*  which won't be possible with filter ... And the straight forward solution to this problem without manipulating loop indexes is traversing the array backwards ...

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about that.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. So the `i--` and stay with `splice` would be better option.